# Rf module getting signals when i use ssh, but not when i send it from the transmitter

Tags: raspberry-pi, project, gpio, microprocessors

For some reason, my Rf receiver get data on the gpio pin when I use `ssh`, but not when I send a signal using the transmitter.
[result when I'm using the transmitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTfvE.png)

And when I use `ssh` to connect to my Pi:

[data caught on gpio when using ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htoAl.png)

[Raspberry pi setup, i'm using a Pi 1 B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62L9e.png)

I want to capture and emit radio signals.

Comment: What is frequency on board? The frequency is depending on country.

Comment: Please don't post images of text; just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Sorry, its my first time posting, il note to not post snippets. Alson im from Serbia and the standard is 433Mhz, the same as the module frequency.